# Extract same customer from different customer names

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working on a sales report. In the Customer_Name column, the full name of customer is provided, however, what happens very often is that they are actually the same customer with different locations, a minimal example would be like following:

```
library(tidyverse)
customer_purchase_history <- tibble(
Customer_Name=c("Google Facility A","Google LA","Google European","Apple California LA","Apple Store Chicago"),
Purchase_Amount=c(100,2000,30000,450,20))
```

Can I detect which customer names are from the same customer and then extract the name they are sharing, then I would be able to calculate the aggregated sales.

I am a tidyverse user and aiming for a tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 0):

If all customer name is the first element of the "Customer_Name" and all are separated by a space, you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
customer_purchase_history %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Customer = unlist(strsplit(Customer_Name," "))[1])


# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Customer_Name       Purchase_Amount Customer
  <chr>                         <dbl> <chr>   
1 Google Facility A               100 Google  
2 Google LA                      2000 Google  
3 Google European               30000 Google  
4 Apple California LA             450 Apple   
5 Apple Store Chicago              20 Apple
```

Comment: Hi dc37, thanks a lot for your fast response. However, the Company name may be in the middle of the full name and there are only few cases it appears in the beginning.

Comment: Without a clear pattern how to identify each company name, it will be hard to detect the right pattern. Do you have a list of customer name ? If so, you can match the list to "Customer_Name"

Comment: I don't have a list on hand and it seems i might need to create one to make this to work. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Sorry to not be able to help you. Good luck with the next.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
# create new column for company names
customer_purchase_history$company_name_new = NA
# make a list of company names
Company_names = c("Apple", "Google")

# we'll use tryCatch() to handle any exceptions
for (i in 1:nrow(customer_purchase_history)) {
  tryCatch({
    words = unlist(strsplit(customer_purchase_history$Customer_Name[i], split = " "))
   customer_purchase_history$company_name_new[i] = intersect(Company_names, words)
  }, error = function(e) {
      print(paste("row", i , "has no company name", sep = " "))
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I am trying to understand your code.